# Pass data from app components[textbox] to website components[textbox]

Tags: javascript, android

I am working on an app for an website(to which I have no access).

So I want to do the following: [image: link]

So how do I pass the text data from my android view to the textboxes in the webpage
and also capture the response coming from the web site?

All this I am trying to do keeping in mind ***I have no access to the website code whatsoever***.

So any tips or suggestions for me to suggest in the correct path?

Comment: [This](http://www.cuelogic.com/blog/?s=simple%20android%20java%20javascript%20bridge) might help.

Comment: @Nun'eChai
what might help?

EDIT: my bad didnt see the hyperlink on "this"

Answer (score 0):

1. create a database.
2. A table and field username, password
3. create android api.(using php)
4. pass username and password from android app to server using asynchronous task.
5. do your task in OnPostexecute.
6. pass your data from server to website using simple php file.
   done it.

Comment: hi,my question here is how do i 
put the data onto the textboxes in the webpage
(i dont not have access to the code of the webpage)

and also get the submit button on the webpage clicked
when i press submit on my app screen
and capture the response from the webpage